# reading csv file from R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am new to R and want to read a csv file. But I got error when I try to read it. 
My csv file are as follow:

```
,Zbot,Sirefef,Fareit,Winwebsec,FakeSysdef,Winwebsec,Winwebsec,Winwebsec,Fareit,Fareit,Sirefef,Winwebsec,Winwebsec,Winwebsec,Winwebsec
Zbot,0,134,45,651,182,245,986,64,63,34,134,166,52,337,225
Sirefef,142,0,124,679,200,273,1018,156,125,122,164,198,120,371,257
Fareit,48,124,0,644,166,234,978,82,64,51,135,167,49,338,224
Winwebsec,651,499,470,0,575,556,1087,525,490,485,501,511,483,600,582
FakeSysdef,178,172,143,535,0,311,1052,196,163,152,204,234,154,405,285
Winwebsec,245,199,168,478,229,0,997,217,186,183,199,209,183,348,272
Winwebsec,986,752,719,821,784,727,0,774,739,734,750,760,734,851,829
Winwebsec,80,160,85,506,179,204,757,0,100,85,173,205,89,376,264
Fareit,65,95,32,468,141,164,715,78,0,57,135,165,59,336,226
Fareit,52,122,51,468,143,166,717,68,40,0,135,163,49,336,224
Sirefef,136,118,85,449,150,147,696,123,83,83,0,146,100,317,207
Winwebsec,164,138,105,449,170,145,696,143,103,103,80,0,118,315,215
Winwebsec,52,116,51,466,143,166,717,66,42,32,83,103,0,336,226
Winwebsec,335,267,234,496,301,246,745,272,232,234,213,213,234,0,346
Winwebsec,225,204,171,519,228,217,774,207,169,169,150,160,169,291,0
```

And when I use this command in RStudio I got error:
Command:

```
> tb = read.csv("/home/hossein/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/test.csv", row.names = 1);
```

error:

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

I also try to remove the error and use this command:

```
 > tb = read.csv("/home/hossein/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/test.csv", row.names = NULL);
```

but when i view the output is that it can not keep the structure of the square matrix. Could you help me what should I do?

Comment: First of all, the first line of the dataset starts with a comma. Second, why don't you try using the GUI feature of loading datasets with RStudio? If you do that, you might get a better chance at detecting why your data is not loading properly.

Answer (score 2):

R do not support duplicated row names, see `?row.names`:

> All data frames have a row names attribute, a character vector of length the number of rows with no duplicates nor missing values.

Given this, you can import your data then make row names unique with the function `make.names`. This is a bit ugly, but I think it solves your problem. See the example below with the data you provided.

```r
table <- read.csv("data.csv", row.names = NULL)

### Save row names in a separte object:
rows <- table$X

### Remove the colunm with row.names:
table <- table[,-1]

### Create unique Row.names with the function `make.names`
rownames(table) <- make.names(rows, unique=TRUE)

### Check results:
dim(table)
#> [1] 15 15
head(table)
#>             Zbot Sirefef Fareit Winwebsec FakeSysdef Winwebsec.1
#> Zbot           0     134     45       651        182         245
#> Sirefef      142       0    124       679        200         273
#> Fareit        48     124      0       644        166         234
#> Winwebsec    651     499    470         0        575         556
#> FakeSysdef   178     172    143       535          0         311
#> Winwebsec.1  245     199    168       478        229           0
#>             Winwebsec.2 Winwebsec.3 Fareit.1 Fareit.2 Sirefef.1
#> Zbot                986          64       63       34       134
#> Sirefef            1018         156      125      122       164
#> Fareit              978          82       64       51       135
#> Winwebsec          1087         525      490      485       501
#> FakeSysdef         1052         196      163      152       204
#> Winwebsec.1         997         217      186      183       199
#>             Winwebsec.4 Winwebsec.5 Winwebsec.6 Winwebsec.7
#> Zbot                166          52         337         225
#> Sirefef             198         120         371         257
#> Fareit              167          49         338         224
#> Winwebsec           511         483         600         582
#> FakeSysdef          234         154         405         285
#> Winwebsec.1         209         183         348         272
as.dist(table)
#>             Zbot Sirefef Fareit Winwebsec FakeSysdef Winwebsec.1
#> Sirefef      142                                                
#> Fareit        48     124                                        
#> Winwebsec    651     499    470                                 
#> FakeSysdef   178     172    143       535                       
#> Winwebsec.1  245     199    168       478        229            
#> Winwebsec.2  986     752    719       821        784         727
#> Winwebsec.3   80     160     85       506        179         204
#> Fareit.1      65      95     32       468        141         164
#> Fareit.2      52     122     51       468        143         166
#> Sirefef.1    136     118     85       449        150         147
#> Winwebsec.4  164     138    105       449        170         145
#> Winwebsec.5   52     116     51       466        143         166
#> Winwebsec.6  335     267    234       496        301         246
#> Winwebsec.7  225     204    171       519        228         217
#>             Winwebsec.2 Winwebsec.3 Fareit.1 Fareit.2 Sirefef.1
#> Sirefef                                                        
#> Fareit                                                         
#> Winwebsec                                                      
#> FakeSysdef                                                     
#> Winwebsec.1                                                    
#> Winwebsec.2                                                    
#> Winwebsec.3         757                                        
#> Fareit.1            715          78                            
#> Fareit.2            717          68       40                   
#> Sirefef.1           696         123       83       83          
#> Winwebsec.4         696         143      103      103        80
#> Winwebsec.5         717          66       42       32        83
#> Winwebsec.6         745         272      232      234       213
#> Winwebsec.7         774         207      169      169       150
#>             Winwebsec.4 Winwebsec.5 Winwebsec.6
#> Sirefef                                        
#> Fareit                                         
#> Winwebsec                                      
#> FakeSysdef                                     
#> Winwebsec.1                                    
#> Winwebsec.2                                    
#> Winwebsec.3                                    
#> Fareit.1                                       
#> Fareit.2                                       
#> Sirefef.1                                      
#> Winwebsec.4                                    
#> Winwebsec.5         103                        
#> Winwebsec.6         213         234            
#> Winwebsec.7         160         169         291
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that when use the Null then by using this command  d = as.dist(tb) I got this error: Warning messages:
1: In as.dist.default(tb) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as.dist.default(tb) : non-square matrix

Comment: The problem is that duplicated row names are not allowed. see `?read.csv`.  But you can "hack" this problem with `make.names`. I will update the answer, then you let me know if it works for you. Cheers

Comment: Updated the answer... Please see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few simple steps as follows:

```
d = read.csv('path/to/test.csv') # import the data
row.names(d) = make.unique(as.character(d[, 1])) # create the row names from the first column
d = d[, -1] # remove the first column now that you don't need it anymore
```

This maintains your square matrix:

```
dim(d) # still a 15x15 matrix
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but I got different dimensions: [1] 15 16

Comment: I just double checked it and I'm still getting 15x15 with the csv file you copy above...

Answer (score 0):

The first row starts with a blank field, so it might be convenient to use the `skip = 1` argument, perhaps since `read.csv` not understand the input function as a rectangular array.